# google calendar functions

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

does anyone know how to create a form to add a google calendar event? It has to have tons of additional fields that just need to go into the body of the event. The code I got from the API is nonfunctional. I'd like to do it with php

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own form however you like. That really does not have any connection to the API.

In order to manipulate Google Calendar from your own site you will have to use the Google Calendar Data API.
The official guide to it is here:  http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html

If you want to use PHP I would highly recommend using the Zend Framework, since it makes using the API a lot easier.

Zend has the functionality to deal with the Google Calendar API.

Documentation is here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html